# BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE with multiple material numbers and same PP order?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi, function-module

As I know of, When you're using BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE at the same time(by loop or just coincidence), Using same material number puts you an error about locked object (Material XXXX is locked by USER YYYY).

But, as i know of, using BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE at the same time, but different material number WITH same production order makes no error.

**Issue**

Recently I found an error about M3/897 (Plant Data of Material XXXX is locked by user XXXX) when I'm doing BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE when I'm trying GI for Production order, by parallel processing, which are putting different Material number to same production order.

**Question**

So, I'm asking about constraint of BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE.

So far I know is -

A. You can't issue GI for Production Order(Mvt 261) at the same time, when you're putting *same material number for different production order*.

B. (I'm not sure about this) You can't issue GI for Production Order(Mvt 261) at the same time, when you're putting *different material number for same production order*.

Is both is right, or just A is right? Any help from experienced ABAPer or MM consultant would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

To post GI in a loop you need to make commit after each run, and unlock the object explicitly, otherwise you will get the PP lock.

Try like this:

```
LOOP AT lt_orders ASSIGNING <fs>.
...
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE'
 EXPORTING
  goodsmvt_header  = ls_header
  goodsmvt_code    = ls_code
 IMPORTING
  goodsmvt_headret = ls_headret
  materialdocument = ls_retmtd
 TABLES
  goodsmvt_item    = lt_item
  return           = lt_return.

 IF line_exists( lt_return[ type = 'E' ] ).

  CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK'.

 ELSE.

  COMMIT WORK AND WAIT.
  CALL FUNCTION 'DEQUEUE_ALL'.

 ENDIF.

ENDLOOP.
```

Always use BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT with WAIT parameter or COMMIT WORK with the same after each BAPI call.

Also there can be tricky issues with the GR and implicit GI movements, see the note [369518](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/369518) about this.

Comment: Sorry for late response - and thanks for replying.

The problem is, because of current specific situation of process, we're doing mass GI posting at the first day of month(like, line item of.. 300k+), so we split each document with 300 line items.
And We're currently implementing parallel processing method.. so we don't know the BAPI is locked or not when we're running that programs.

The real reason why I'm asking this is - How do i avoid lock error, by finding constraint of BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE, so I can changing grouping rules to avoid this error.

Comment: Like, binding line item with same material code AND different production order.
It seems I can avoid this error with spliting line item with more documents, like 50 line item for each document, by your answer.. Am I right?

Comment: probably the above coding will not help you with parallel processing. Theoretically you can group the lines by PP order number, but you may end up with material lock if the same material is included in multiple orders. Right now it's hard to say if it would work. All in all you didn't put anything about parallelism in your question, it's totally another story. For that you should ask a separate question

Answer (score 0):

You can check the presence of existing lock at runtime using this FM - "ENQUE_READ2".

data: RAW_ENQ        like LOCKSEDX_ENQ_TAB,
SUBRC          type SY-SUBRC,
NUMBER         type I.

```
clear : RAW_ENQ[], SUBRC, NUMBER.

add 1 to COUNTER.
call function 'ENQUE_READ2'
  importing
    SUBRC  = SUBRC
    NUMBER = NUMBER
  tables
    ENQ    = RAW_ENQ.
```

But if you have to prevent a failure of GOODS mvt. in general you have instead to implement some reprocessing logic to store errors.

The steps would be : Catch errors --> store bapi information or header doc number --> retry later

Comment: Yes, I'll put retry logic later, for last resort(in fact, this problem will solve if you do retry several time, it's just lock error).
Enquene check doesn't solve this problem sadly, At the moment when I check enque lock, It could be unlocked, but as I mentionted above comment(which are not in question), it's work like aRFC, so when I try to use BAPI GI posting, It could be unlocked OR locked at that moment.

Comment: I opened another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71865020/bapi-goodsmvt-create-and-parallelism-group-by-material-only-or-more

I'll be appreciated if you help me, Thanks!