# Any workflow assigned to 531 and 261 movement types?

Tags: workflow, abap, sap-erp, bapi, function-module

Follow-up question of [BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE in parallel mode causes "plant data of the material XXX is locked" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71865020/bapi-goodsmvt-create-in-parallel-mode-causes-plant-data-of-the-material-xxx-is).

As I wrote in above question - I'm currently improving program by using parallelism to split one job to multiple job, which are reducing whole work time.

**Problem**

It works great when I do Movement 261 posting, which are reduced working time by half.

The **real** problem is, It's not working for Movement 531 posting, which cause standard lock error - Material **A** is locked by user **Material A**, which are seems to be odd to me(I think correct one would be Material A is locked by user **USERNAME**).

**Question**

Is there a workflow of 531 posting, whenever i post these documents? like, changing MARDH, MCHB, AUFM tables, which can be investigated so i can find root cause of locked error.

Currently, whenever I try parallel job - I have to do multiple times because locked entry does not processed(fortunately it's just locked error, so how many times i retry this process, it doesn't affect data consistancy), which are annyoing because i have to monitor this CBO  program whole time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tcode `SWELS` to trace workflow events:

Step 1. Execute transaction SWELS 
Step 2. Run posting of 531 movement via BAPI or in MIGO 
Step 3. Execute transaction SWEL

in SWEL report you will see all workflow processes and events that were triggered

**UPDATE**: do not forget to check the restrictions for trace

[image]

it may be set a filter by object type that prevents from showing all the events

[image]

Comment: I tried but It returns only recode 'Confirmation' event, is there a restriction for SWELS?

Comment: @ParkChanSeul check my edit

Comment: It shows only 'FINALCONFIRMATION' and 'ORDER_CONFIRMATION_CREATE' Event, nothing else. Do I have to assign these event to something else? like SPRO(IMG) setting.

Comment: no, it means there are no 532-related WF events happens. I have the same on my system, just tested, I ran 531 mtype and no events were captured. Confirmation events you posted are unrelated to 531